# Encrypted data is larger than the input data

Tags: android, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data using AES but I dont know why the output is larger than the input.
I used this function to derive the key

```
public byte[] deriveKey(String p, byte[] s, int i, int l) throws Exception {

    PBEKeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(p.toCharArray(), s, i, l);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    return skf.generateSecret(ks).getEncoded();
}
```

After that I send the data which is (112 bytes) and the key to the encrypt function but I get encrypted data (154 bytes)

```
public String encrypt(String s,byte[] d) throws Exception {

    // Perform Encryption
    SecretKeySpec eks = new SecretKeySpec(d, "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, eks, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    byte[] es = c.doFinal(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

Comment: Encryption is not a compression. The encryption result can be bigger or smaller depending on the encryption method.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך But not in the OPs case.  Since he is using CTR mode, the resulting ciphertext should be the exact same byte-length as the plaintext.

Comment: Your example was incomplete. You encrypt function returns a String, but the last statement in it returns a byte array. My guess is your are then base64 encoding the result before returning it, which would account for the size of the result.

Answer (score 0):

The plaintext that you want to encrypt is a string (`s`) which you encode to a byte array right before encryption: `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

If the plaintext string contains non-ASCII characters (code points 128 and up), those will be encoded as two or more bytes with UTF-8 (see the table in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)). English text will likely consist of the same number of bytes as characters. Other languages might not be so lucky and their encoding from string to binary data will be blown up.

CTR mode is a streaming mode of operation, so the plaintext/ciphertext input will always be the same size as the ciphertext/plaintext output. The problem is of course that a scheme like AES-CTR has three inputs: key, data and an IV/nonce.

***Only*** if you're changing the password/key every time you encrypt, using a static zero-byte IV will be somewhat secure. If you reuse the password/key even once, you'll run into the two-time pad (many-time pad) problem where an attacker who simply observes ciphertexts might deduce the plaintexts just by looking at them ([nice example](https://twitter.com/angealbertini/status/425561082841690112/photo/1)).

If you cannot guarantee the single use of password/key, then you must use a new IV every time you encrypt. No more `new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16])`, but something like

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
r.nextBytes(iv);
Arrays.fill(iv, 12, 16, (byte)0); // zero out the counter part
```

Answer (score -1):

In many encryption algorithms, padding is inevitable. That's why you see a size increase on cipher. This post might be helpful to you to understand what happens: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29993/aes-cbc-padding-when-the-message-length-is-a-multiple-of-the-block-size

Comment: The need for padding is not determined by the cipher itself, but by the block mode.  CTR mode, by definition, does not need padding.  Notice that in the article you link the mode used is CBC, **not** CTR.

Comment: The code supplied specifies no padding: `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");`